# Build Java Bean From another one

Tags: java

I want to build a VO to produce JSON from another VO and I can do it in 2 differents way, I would like to know witch one is better for you:

First way is to set some variables in the constructors

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public static class SkuDataVO implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    private String skuTitle;
    @JsonProperty
    private String headline;
    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal originalPrice;
    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal offerPrice;
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer cap;
    @JsonProperty
    private BigDecimal postagePerUnit;
    @JsonProperty
    private Float revenueShare;

    public SkuDataVO(SubmissionSku submissionSku, String title, String headline) {
        this.skuTitle = title;
        this.headline = headline;
        this.originalPrice = submissionSku.getOriginalPrice();
        this.offerPrice = submissionSku.getPrice();
        this.cap = submissionSku.getCap();
        this.revenueShare = submissionSku.getRevenueShare();
        this.postagePerUnit = submissionSku.getPostageCost();
    }

    //getter on variables
```

Second way is to call the getter of the second VO in the getters.

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public static class SkuDataVO implements Serializable {

            @JsonProperty
            private String skuTitle;
            @JsonProperty
            private String headline;
            @JsonIgnore
            private SubmissionSku submissionSku;

            public SkuDataVO(SubmissionSku submissionSku, String title, String headline) {
                this.submissionSku = submissionSku;
                this.skuTitle = title;
                this.headline = headline;
            }

        @JsonProperty
        public BigDecimal getOriginalPrice() {
            return submissionSku.getOriginalPrice();
        }

         @JsonProperty
         public BigDecimal getOfferPrice() {
            return submissionSku.getPrice();
         }

         @JsonProperty
         public Integer getCap() {
            return submissionSku.getCap();
         }

        @JsonProperty
        public Float getRevenueShare() {
            return submissionSku.getRevenueShare();
        }

        @JsonProperty
        public BigDecimal getPostagePerUnit() {
            return submissionSku.getPostageCost();
        }

        public String getSkuTitle() {
            return skuTitle;
        }

         public String getHeadline() {
            return headline;
         }
```

Comment: Please use BeanUtils from apache commons

Comment: it's an idea but if the var names are different between the objects, it's not so convenient..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look to [`@JsonUnwrapped` annotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUnwrapping). I think it's exactly what you need for your use case:

```
public static class SkuDataVO implements Serializable {

    public String skuTitle;

    public String headline;

    @JsonUnwrapped // <-- magic happens here
    public SubmissionSku submissionSku;

    public SkuDataVO(SubmissionSku submissionSku, String title, String headline) {
        this.submissionSku = submissionSku;
        this.skuTitle = title;
        this.headline = headline;
    }
}
```

I've used `public` fields because this is not an actual object, but just a *DTO (Data Transfer Object)* you use to format your JSON appropriately.

Besides, I don't think you actually need to use `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonAutoDetect`, since you aren't changing default Jackson behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In my opionion the first approach would be the better way to go.
As i understand it you only need this VO to create JSON and once from the Values in your other VO, so there would be no explicit need to have the other VO (for example a value update in SkuDataVO by updating the values in the SubmissionSkuVO) so i think you could use the VO as a simple "storage" for the data to serialize and deserialize. Also for someone just seeing the "outside" of your class the impicit update behaviour might be a bit confusing if they have no access to the decompiled source code.
Regards